# How to retain the reference of the image view in GirdView item (prevent recycling) after scrolling

Tags: java, android, multithreading, gridview, concurrency

I have a GridView, where the item has ImageView, and the image is downloaded in (`Thread`) not AsyncTasK, After scrolling the GridView, the ImageView is being recycled. I have found solution for this problem in case I as using AysncTask ([see this link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)) But how to handle concurrency in GridView in case I am using Thread class.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're using a Tread and not an AsyncTask, it should just store the image in some sort of container (since you have a GridView I suppose you have many other elements). If they're all of the same type, try storing them inside and ArrayList (if the GridItems are only an ImageView) and give the array to a subclassed Adapter. The Adapter should take care of displaying the elements inside the GridView.